# How to disable the security certificate check for Google Translate

Tags: python, ssl, google-translate

I have to use google translator API to translate Japanese to English for my NLTP project.
This is the sample code I am using:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
translator.translate('学生')
```

I am getting an SSL certificate error:

> ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
> failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)

I know I have to disable the security certificate check. How to do this for Google Translate module?

I tried this and it is not working-

```
import requests, os
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False
session.trust_env = False
```

Please, help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error is from httpx libray calling api with ssl verify. we can desable this by editing the following code.

1. go to this file - ....\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py
2. or you can open this file directly from IDE (press cntrl + click the "Translate" class name)
3. on "cline.py"  file under Translate class -> **init** -> on the first line
4. edit this line

   self. client = httpx.Client(http2=http2)

to

```
self.client = httpx.Client(http2=http2, verify=False)
```

5. save file and run again